# Execution failed for task ' :clean' when doing the clean build for gradle java

Tags: gradle, build, gradlew

I was doing the build for my project so i got 6 exception similar to this for different files after executing below command-

**./gradlew clean build --parallel -x test publishlocal**

### Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':clean'.

  > Unable to delete file: /home/user/folder1/projectfolder/buildDir/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF

### Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':modulename:clean'.

  > Unable to delete file: /home/user/folder1/projectfolder/modulename/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF

i was following below steps before this command-

1. jps -q| xargs -i{} kill -9 {}
2. time ./gradlew -b gradle/xyz-plugin/build.gradle build
3. ./gradlew clean build --parallel -x test publishlocal

if any one know let me know. thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you reconfigured the `clean` task in any way? The is an open issue about task ordering when making it depend on other tasks, which might be what is hitting you (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2488).